# How can I hide $Aborted message?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I know that I'm aborting the evaluation and can see it when the black bar on the side goes away. So there is no need for this message. How do I turn it off?

Comment: That is technically not a message, but a returned expression.

Comment: ok.. is there a way to not display it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not using `$Post` for something else, or if you can combine functions, you could use:

```
$Post = # /. $Aborted -> Null &;
```

Be warned that you may break things, as programs may use `$Aborted` in their control flow.

---

More robustly, addressing the problem Alexey demonstrates:

```
$Post = Function[Null, Unevaluated@# /. $Aborted -> Null, HoldAllComplete];
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this session dependent or will it persist across all sessions?

Comment: Environment variables are not persistent.  I use Kernel/init.m in the user directory to set things like `$HistoryLength` etc.

Comment: I see... Is `$HistoryLength` for number of undos?

Comment: I was thinking something similar but at the other end: use $Pre to wrap everything in a `CheckAbort[#,Null]&` but it didn't work... :(

Comment: @d00b no, you only get one Undo in Mathematica.  `$HistoryLength` controls how many output expressions are saved for `%`, `%%`, etc., and for `Out[n]`.  I use `$HistoryLength = 3` so that I can use `%%%` but not use up too much memory.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks. The one undo sucks though.

Comment: @Simon, I tried using `$PrePrint` first to be less heavy-duty, but doesn't prevent the creation of the output cell, so you get `Null`.  I don't like using `$Post` this way, but I cannot think of another method.

Comment: @d00b you're not the first to complain about that, and you won't be the last, but there are some fairly compelling explanations for why it's that way.  I am still not 100% convinced though.

Comment: @Mr. @d00b Use the Wolfram Workbench, as real men do :)

Comment: @belisarius: You [weren't kidding](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/features/edit.html)! It does have a lot more to offer. However, only cheap versions for me for now.

Comment: @yoda yep. The student version is $145

Comment: @belisarius, my school provides free access to workbench for grad students, but I found its development methodology to be exactly the opposite of how I program with Mathematica. So, despite its many good things, it annoyed me the entire time I used it.

Comment: @rcollyer I think there is a clear trade-off there. I use the Workbench only for things bigger than three screens. I like the Notebook interactivity, and Eclipse is not my favorite piece of software, but I reckon that writing a moderately large program needs **at least** a robust undo (and refactor, and a lot of other WB goodies)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This code works incorrectly for inputs having `Head`s `Sequence` and `Unevaluated`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

The following is a generalization of the `$Pre`-based method suggested by Simon and the `$Post`-based method suggested by Mr.Wizard.

In both cases one should set `HoldAllComplete` attribute to the pure functions and wrap `x` (input expression) inside them by `Unevaluated` so they work correctly with inputs having `Head`s `Sequence`, `Unevaluated` and `Evaluate`.

Compare two versions of the `$Pre`-based solution:

```
f1 = Function[{x}, CheckAbort[x, Null], {HoldAll}]
f2 = Function[{x}, CheckAbort[Unevaluated@x, Null], {HoldAllComplete}]

In[3]:= f1@Sequence[1,2]
f1@Abort[]
f1@Evaluate[Abort[]]
f1@Unevaluated[1+1]
Out[3]= 1
Out[5]= $Aborted
Out[6]= 2

In[7]:= f2@Sequence[1,2]
f2@Evaluate[Abort[]]
f2@Unevaluated[1+1]
Out[7]= Sequence[1,2]
Out[9]= Unevaluated[1+1]
```

One can see that the first version can easily be broken with `Evaluate[Abort[]]` and works incorrectly with input expressions having `Head`s `Sequence` and `Unevaluated`. It is generally true for any one-argument function without `HoldAllComplete` attribute. Since `$Pre`, `$Post` and friends all are one-argument functions one must always set `HoldAllComplete` attribute to them.

I also see no problems with using `Null` as the second argument of `CheckAbort` (there is no need for `Return@Null`). On my machine (*Mathematica* 7.0.1 under Windows 2000) `$Abort` is never returned in the case of the `f2`.

The same is true for the `$Post`-based solution. It can be generalized as follows:

```
$Post = Function[x, If[Unevaluated@x =!= $Aborted, Unevaluated@x], 
  HoldAllComplete]
```

Test expressions:

```
In[14]:= Unevaluated[1+2]
Sequence[1,2]
$Aborted
Abort[]
Out[14]= Unevaluated[1+2]
Out[15]= Sequence[1,2]
```

Comment: +1 Alexey.  I also updated my answer now.  You might want to rewrite your answer in a primary format, that is, such that it is not subordinate to the other answers, in case it is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The following **seems** to work:

```
SetAttributes[katch, HoldAll];
katch[x_] := CheckAbort[x, Return@Null] 
$Pre = katch;
```

After testing, remember to return $Pre to its previous value:

```
$Pre =.
```

Probably interferes with some internal abort catching, though.

**Edit**

Simon's version:

```
$Pre = Function[{x}, CheckAbort[x,Return@Null], {HoldAll}]
```

Comment: +1: Yes, that's what I was trying to do. It can be made a one-liner `$Pre = Function[{x}, CheckAbort[x, Null], {HoldAll}]`.